# How to resolve illegal constructor error when using this as input in constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have the following error:

```
TypeError: Illegal constructor
    at new Car (car.js:15:23)
    at main.js:7:13
```

The car constructor is here and line

```
constructor(x, y, width, height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;    
        this.controls = new Controls();
        this.sensor = new Sensor(this);
    }
```

The error is being thrown on `this.sensor = new Sensor(this);`

The creation of the car object looks like this:

`const car = new Car(2, 100, 30, 50);`

Any idea why I'm getting this error? I think I should be able to use `this` as a parameter, so not sure why the error is getting thrown

This is the class Sensor that I'm using:

```
class Sensor{
    constructor(car){
        this.car = car;
        this.rayCount = 3;
        this.rayLength = 100;
        this.raySpread = Math.PI / 4;
        this.rays = [];
    }

    update(){
        this.rays = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.rayCount; i++){
            const rayAngle = lerp(
                this.raySpread / 2, 
                - this.raySpread / 2, 
                i / (this.rayCount - 1)
            );

            const start = {x : this.car.x, y: this.car.y};
            const end = {
                x: this.car.x - Math.sin(rayAngle) * this.rayLength,
                y: this.car.y - Math.cos(rayAngle) * this.rayLength
            };

            this.rays.push([start, end]);
        }
    }

    draw(context) {
        for(let i = 0; i < this.rayCount; i++){
            context.beginPath();
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.strokeStyle = "yellow";
            context.moveTo(
                this.rays[i][0].x,
                this.rays[i][0].y
            );
            context.lineTo(
                this.rays[i][1].x, 
                this
            );
            context.stroke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Sensor`?

Comment: Sensor and Controls are additional classes I've created.

Answer (score 0):

change which line "this" on from this

```js
constructor(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    this.sensor = new Sensor(this);
    this.controls = new Controls
to this
    constructor(x, y, width, height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        this.sensor = new Sensor(this);
        this.controls = new Controls
```

Comment: There's no difference?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).